# Find locus of point vertex of right angle triangle whose hypotenuse is chord of circle.

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Let $AB$ be a variable chord of length 5 to the circle $$x^2+y^2=\frac{25}{2}$$. A triangle $ABC$ is constructed such that $BC=4$ and $CA=3$. If the locus of C is $x^2+y^2=a$ find all possible values of $a$

I tried using the parametric form to solve this question but it resulted in a very cumbersome task with no avail because of so much of variables and their eliminations. Can anyone explain any easier method to solve it. [image]

Comment: sorry i don't understand all,where is the right angle situated?

Comment: There are two cases- the vertex C can lie either inside the circle or outside the circle that means there will be two locii of point C

Comment: can you make a Image please?

Comment: Draw a image, take a photo and upload it

Comment: I have posted the two cases I think of

Comment: You wrote $CA=6$. Why in the picture it is $CA=3$?

Comment: Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the particular position of $A\left(-\frac52,\frac52\right);\;B\left(\frac52,\frac52\right)$

The line $AC_2$ has equation $y-\frac{5}{2}=\frac{4}{3} \left(x+\frac{5}{2}\right)$

And the circle with center $A$ and radius $3$ has equation $\left(x+\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2=9$

The intersection point is $C_2(-0.7,\;4.9)$

Similarly for $AC_1$. The equation is $y-\frac{5}{2}=-\frac{4}{3} \left(x+\frac{5}{2}\right)$

Intersecting with the same circle center $A$ and radius $3$ we get

$C_1(-0.7,0.1)$

The radii of the two loci are

$OC_1=\sqrt{0.7^2+0.1^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

so the first value for $a_1=\frac12$

And $OC_2=\sqrt{0.7^2+4.9^2}=\frac{7}{\sqrt{2}}$

and we get $a_2=\frac{49}{2}$

Hope this helps

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: As of now I just know one value of a and it is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Could you please elaborate your method

Comment: @Greninja Previous method was crazy. This is much  simpler! Hope you like it...